# How to pass parameters in a frame using php

Tags: php, parameters, parameter-passing, frame

I want to pass a parameter to a php file in the frame but how i can do this. Currently i have tried this method (i am not sure about this method) to pass a parameter to frame2.php by passing an `id` value to frame2.php

```
<frameset cols = "25%, *">
  <frame src ="frame1.php" />
  <frame id="<?php echo "$pid"; ?>" src ="frame2.php" />
</frameset>
```

in `frame2.php` I tried to call that id using this method

```
<?php
$pid=$_GET['id']; //also tried $_POST['id'];
echo "$pid";
<--other php codes-->
?>
```

But its not working ... can you tell me why it doesn't worked or what other method i can use to pass the parameters

Advanced thanks for your help

Comment: `<frame id="<?php echo "$pid"; ?>" src ="frame2.php?id=<?php echo $pid; ?>" />`

Comment: try something like this src="frame2.php?id=<?php echo $pid; ?>" and then use Get at frame2

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code i can suggest you the following code.

```
<frameset cols = "25%, *">
  <frame src ="frame1.php" />
  <frame id="<?php echo "$pid"; ?>" src ="frame2.php?id="<?php echo "$pid"; ?>" />
</frameset>
```

And on the server side you can get it like this

```
<?php
$pid=$_GET['id']; //also you can try $_REQUEST['id'];
echo "$pid";
<--other php codes-->
?>
```